# Why is this Promise not getting resolved?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I created a function that reads an external JSON file and returns a promise. It was working fine but suddenly stopped working. Here's my code where the error is occuring.

```
export let readJSON = async (file) => {
    const request = async () => {
        const response = await $.get(`${jsonPath}/${file}`);
        return response; 
    }
    return await request();
}
```

Here's the function call

```
readJSON("admin-form.json").then( i => {
        let opts = $.extend({}, i, options )
        formBuilder(opts);
    } ).catch(e => console.error(e))
```

and here's the error that I am getting in console
[image]

I even changed my code to

```
export let readJSON = async (file) => $.get(`${jsonPath}/${file}`)

readJSON("admin-form.json").then( i => {
        console.log(i)
    } ).catch(e => console.error(e))
```

but error remains.

It was working fine then suddenly stopped working

Comment: please show the actual responseText as text, not a picture, that's unreadable and also incomplete. Thanks.

Comment: This is the only thing That I am getting in console

Comment: P.S. the AJAX status is 200 so it shouldn't have thrown an error. Are you sure there's no other error

Comment: So this is an error that you logged in the `e => console.error(e)` line?

Comment: P.P.S. $.get already returns a Promise. Why do you feel the need to wrap it in all this extra code? It's unclear what you're trying to achieve with it. `$.get(`${jsonPath}/${file}`).then(//...etc)` would do just as well.

Comment: I think you could shorten that to `export const readJson = async (file) => $.get(\`${jsonPath}/${file}\`);`. No need to `await` it twice (!), just return the promise directly.

Comment: Is this your exact `readJSON` code? Although really garbled, it should work (and never return or throw the jQuery ajax object).

Comment: yes. This is the only error that I am getting through `.catch(e => console.error(e))`

Comment: did you check if the response changed, maybe the error happened after in `let opts = $.extend({}, i, options )
        formBuilder(opts);`

Comment: In your image, the error is thrown from `formBuilder.js`. Is the code snippet belongs to that file?

Comment: @YongQuan. Yes.

Comment: @ShayMoshe. Yes.

Comment: why not add a `try..catch` block inside `readJSON` function (or the `.then` after it) to debug?

Comment: @ShayMoshe I tried to comment everything inside the `then()` but still the error remains

Comment: Try just `$.get(`${jsonPath}/${file}`).then(function(data) { console.log(data); });` and see if it crashes. If not then the problem is not the AJAX. I'm fairly sure it's not the ajax already because it appears to return a 200 OK status. That would not cause the Promise to be rejected, or an exception to occur.

Comment: try to change `return await request();
}` to `return request();
}` or just `return request;`

Comment: @ShayMoshe. Still not working

Comment: @Thomas. I tried your solution. but nothing happend

Comment: can you `console.log(readJSON("admin-form.json"))` (change back to your original code) I don't sure it will return you a promise, I think it will return the result.

Comment: I ran this in console `jQuery.get("json/admin-form.json").then(i=>console.log(i))` This is the response `{state: ƒ, always: ƒ, catch: ƒ, pipe: ƒ, then: ƒ, …}
always: ƒ ()
catch: ƒ (e)
done: ƒ ()
fail: ƒ ()
pipe: ƒ ()
progress: ƒ ()
promise: ƒ (e)
state: ƒ ()
then: ƒ (t,r,i)
__proto__: Object`

Comment: I edited my question and simplified my code. Please check

Comment: The confusion is partly arising because what you're showing us in the console is _not an error_ ...it's just a standard jQuery AJAX response object. And that object shows that the AJAX request succeeded. It's really not clear why you're seeing this and what you think the problem is. What did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: @ADyson but why it is executing in `catch(e => console.error(e))` block

Comment: The other unhelpful thing for us that we can't see your options variable or your formbuilder() function, so we can't see if that code is problematic somehow.

Comment: @ADyson All this is getting stored in `e`

Comment: That's unclear. Are you sure that's what's happening? Just for certainty, remove the catch and see what occurs when you run it

Comment: @ADyson I remove `catch` and I got this is console `Uncaught (in promise) {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}`

Comment: I believe the HTTP request was successful but the attempt to parse the data was not, do you have access to the data?

Comment: @ADyson. Thank you for you help. There was a parse error in my `admin-form.json` file

Comment: @ShayMoshe you're aright. The problem was with my data

Comment: @Waeez, great! please answer your qustion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a parse error in my json file that I was trying to read `admin-form.json`